# Unabele to pass product object to child html from product list

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to call a child html element from product listing page. To do that I have added below in catalog.xml

```
         <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="core/template" name="timer" template="catalog/product/deal/timer.phtml" />
..
..
             </block>
          </reference>
```

Then from list.phtml I added below,

```
            <?php
                $this->getChild('timer')->setData("product", $_product); 
                echo $this->getChildHtml('timer')
            ?>
```

Now, In timer.phtml when I print as below,

```
<?php 
    $_product = $this->getProduct();

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_product->getData());
?>
```

It prints only first product data for all products listed in product list page. Assume if there are 10 products in listing page, first product info is being passed to timer.phtml for all remaining 9 products.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set product collection.

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $this->getChild('timer')->setData("product", $_productCollection); 
 ?>
```

timer.phtml as below

```
<?php 
    $_productCollection = $this->getProduct();

    foreach($_productCollection as $_product){

      echo '<pre>'; print_r($_product->getData());

    }
?>
```